# trying to target a property name using the equivalent input name attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm working with an svg built with Raphael, and using a form to make parts of it editable.

I have path variables similar to the following:

```
uk.isle_of_man
uk.republic_of_ireland
uk.england
```

and input fields like:

```
<input id="england-form" type="text" name="england">
```

I'm using the following code to update the fills based on which input field is selected. It's working fine for the id but I'm doing something stupid with `var b = $(this).attr("name");` and trying to use it to target the variable property. Here is the code:

```
$('#form').find('input').focus(function(){
var a = $(this).attr("id");
var b = $(this).attr("name");

$('#'+a).live('change', (function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    uk.(b).color = (value);
}));
```

My intent is that `uk.(b).color` to is equivalent to `uk.england.color`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? It all works fine if I use the `uk.england` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.` it'll search for a property named `b` inside `uk`.
To search for a variable value you have to use `[]`.

So, if I have the following object.

```
var 'uk' = {
    'england': {
        color: 'green'
    },
    'b': {
        color: 'wrong'
    }
};
```

When I use `uk.(b).color`. I get `'wrong'`.
To get `'green'`use `uk[b].color`.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much!! Any idea why that works and the dot doesn't in that instance?